# Make page accessible from another URL

Tags: theme-development

I have the following fictitious URL which returns a page:

www.test.co.uk/park/leisure-village/overview/

Is it possible to make the following URL *www.test.co.uk/park/leisure-village/*, also display the /overview/ page. That is without a redirect though. So *www.test.co.uk/park/leisure-village/* would display what is currently held in *www.test.co.uk/park/leisure-village/overview/* without any form of redirection.

Thanks

Comment: That depends on how the website is functioning in the back-end. You can create a custom template that gets all the content you want and assign that template to both pages.

Answer (score 0):

You should try this plugin.

https://wordpress.org/plugins/insert-pages/

You can insert content of www.test.co.uk/park/leisure-village/overview/  page to www.test.co.uk/park/leisure-village/